# Android MapView: how to show grouped annotations?

Tags: android

I would like to create an Android app that shows the map of the United States with annotations in different cities. When I zoom in a zone I would like to see annotations in single places (e.g. I see NewYork:10 pictures, then I zoom in NY and I see 6 annotations in Central Park and 4 in 5th.avenue, for example). Has anyone already made a similar thing (like in iPhone Photo application and/or an earthquake sample shown on the web using JS GoogleMaps?)